# Integrate Excel VBA code to Java code to finally create the feature of selecting multiple values from the drop down list in a cell of an excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, vba, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have a VBA code for selecting multiple values at once from the drop-down list in a cell of an excel sheet. I want to integrate this code with my java code which allows us to select only 
value at a time from the drop-down list in a cell of an excel sheet using Apache Poi, so that after integration I should finally be able to select multiple values at once from the drop-down list in a cell of an excel sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Java code for selecting only value at a time from the drop-down list in a cell of an excel sheet using Apache Poi

```
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet)sheet);

String[] arrayList = allowedValues.toArray(new String[allowedValues.size()]);

XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(arrayList);

CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(row.getRowNum() + 1, 10000, cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());

XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

validation.createErrorBox("ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid Data", "Please provide valid data in the drop down list.");

sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 1):

The `VBA` code cannot be integrated to the `Java`code which creates the data validation. The `VBA` code runs within the `Excel` `GUI` while the `Java` code only creates the `Excel` file and does not interact with `Excel`'s `GUI` in any case.

Your provided `VBA` code is special code for `Worksheet_Change` event. So it runs every time when something changes on the worksheet it is applied to. So it is able providing additional functionality after someone has selected a value from datavalidation dropdown. It gives the user the possibility to select multiple values, one after the other, for the cell.

What one could do to combinate that with `apache poi` code is having a `*.xlsm` template which has the `Worksheet_Change` applied to a worksheet already. Then `apache poi` can open that template, add data validation and write that to a new `*.xlsm` file.

Example:

`ExcelTemplate.xlsm` has the `Sub`

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim Oldvalue As String
 Dim Newvalue As String
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 On Error GoTo Exitsub
 If Target.Column = 1 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then GoTo Exitsub
  If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Newvalue = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  Oldvalue = Target.Value
  If Oldvalue = "" Then
   Target.Value = Newvalue
  ElseIf InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
   Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
  Else
   Target.Value = Oldvalue
  End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

applied to first worksheet.

Then after following code

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class CreateDataValidation {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String excelTemplatePath = "./ExcelTemplate.xlsm";
  String excelResultPath = "./ExcelResult.xlsm";

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(excelTemplatePath));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  String[] optionsArray = new String[] {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"};

  int no_of_rows = 10000;

  DataValidationConstraint constraint = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createExplicitListConstraint(optionsArray);
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, no_of_rows, 0, 0);
  DataValidation dataValidation = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createValidation(constraint, addressList);
  sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelResultPath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

the `ExcelResult.xlsm` has the datavalidation in first sheet in range `A1:A10001`. And since it has the `Worksheet_Change` `Sub` applied to that sheet too, it provides the additional functionality as long as running macro code will be allowed.